# Get voice input as a mix of predefined grammar and free speech in a UWP application?

Tags: windows, parsing, win-universal-app

Is it possible to get voice input as a mix of predefined grammar(programmatic list constraint/SRGS grammar) and free speech(default dictation grammar) in a UWP application. For example if I say "Search something". Search is a predefined constraint and something is a free form text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. But if the goal is to match intents/actions inside your application (with associated topics) you have another solution. Please try LUIS ([Language Understanding Intelligent Service](http://www.luis.ai)) ; this service is part of Microsoft Cognitive Services.

Just perform a free speech and send the text to this service (once you train it). You can check the following video to obtain additional détails https://www.luis.ai/Help. Note: This is free until 100,000 transactions per month.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jean. The goal is to recognize predefined commands mostly or commands with free speech sometimes. I was using programmatic list constraint for UWP speech recognition but when it comes to searching random text the list constraint wont help,  If the mixed scenario is not supported, i would prefer using default dictation grammar instead. But that also had me stuck at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996184/speech-is-not-being-recognized-with-default-dictation-grammar-in-my-uwp-applicat.