# Speech is not being recognized with default dictation grammar in my UWP application.

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, speech-recognition, windows-10-universal

Speech is not being recognized with default dictation grammar in my UWP application. However, it is perfectly recognized when I use programmatic list constraint. Below is the speech recognition part of my code for reference. If I do not comment the 5th line, this works fine. Am I doing something wrong below:

```
            speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
            bool PermissionGained = await CheckMicrophonePermission();
            if (PermissionGained)
            {
               //speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(new SpeechRecognitionListConstraint(Grammar.GrammarCommands.GrammarConstraintList));
               await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

                //recognize speech input at any point of time 
                speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated +=
                    async (s, e1) =>
                    {
                        if ((e1.Result != null)) 
                        {
                            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                async () =>
                                {
                                    await ParsespeechCommand(e1.Result);

                                });
                             speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Resume();
                        }
                    };
                await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync(SpeechContinuousRecognitionMode.PauseOnRecognition);
            }
```

Comment: I made a demo from your codes(replacing Grammar.GrammarCommands.GrammarConstraintList with a List<String>), everything works fine. Could you set break points and check if Grammar.GrammarCommands.GrammarConstraintList is got by your app correctly?

Comment: Sorry I could not explain my question correctly..this code works perfect with the list constraints as you also experienced but I dont want to use list constraints, I want to use default dictation grammar so that any free speech is recognized. So, In above code I dont want to use the commented 5th line at all which would mean using default dictation grammar. Am I clear?

Comment: I see. Just tried not using constraints. I am not an native English speaker. And sometimes it doesn't recognize either. But most of times it works. Also  using default dictation grammer doesn't mean the free speech can be recognized totally. See [Predefined grammars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/speech-interactions#Constraints).

Comment: Well in my case it doesnt listen at all, did you make any changes? I have set up the microphone and accent does not seem to be a problem.

Comment: Yes, in order to test, I made a few changes. I'll post them for you to check.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed I made a demo and made some changes from the codes.
Here are my codes:

```
private async void myBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        //here I remove the checkPermission process
        var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
        if (true)
        {
            //speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(new SpeechRecognitionListConstraint(new List<string> { "winffee", "Elvis", "noob" }));
            await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

            //recognize speech input at any point of time 
            speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated +=
                async (s, e1) =>
                {
                    if ((e1.Result != null))
                    {
                        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                            () =>//here I remove the async
                            {
                                var result = e1.Result;//here I remove the method to focus on the e1.Result.
                            });
                        speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Resume();
                    }
                };
            await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync(SpeechContinuousRecognitionMode.PauseOnRecognition);
        }
}
```

The whole function is triggered by a button click event. And I made comment on every change position(totally 3 places).

Comment: ok Elvis thanks for posting but none of the changes seem to help too much..I need to await ParseSpeechCommand so I put async... if I move           "await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();" before the continuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated it starts listening sometimes...not most of the times...

Comment: Sorry for late response. I tried adding a async call inside the lamda expression. But the outcome is the same. I would suggest you testing the speech input with  "await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();",which will give an UI to show the result.

Comment: When I remove SpeechContinuousRecognitionMode.PauseOnRecognition, Speech is recognized but session does not resume.... means it recognized speech... corresponding command is executed  but then it stops recognizing. After that it does not recognize anything  Thanks I know about how to get the UI thing but that isnt needed in this app...